# Intel integrated HD4000 graphics and 3D

Tags: display, integrated-graphics, 3d

This is a fairly newbie question that I would like to ask:
I am bit confused about how to reproduce 3D content on the monitor.  I was thinking of getting myself a new laptop with integrated HD 4000 graphics (i5 processor and 6 GB RAM). My questions are:
1) If I buy a 3D monitor will I be able to play 3D video with above mentioned graphics card?
2) If answer above is no, what do I have to have to play 3D movies and watch them on the monitor?

Thanks everyone in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as the monitor is going to be connected using HDMI 1.4 as stated in [Quick Reference Guide to 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processor Graphics (formerly codenamed Ivy Bridge)](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/Quick_Reference_Guide_to_3rd_Generation_Intel_Core_Processor_Graphics.pdf):

**Intel® InTru™ 3D**

> Enjoy the ultimate 3-D visual experience—seamlessly from your PC. Now
>   you can watch your favorite 3-D Blu-ray* movies using passive glasses
>   or active shutter glasses all delivered in full 1080p resolution on
>   your stereo 3-D over HDMI* 1.4.

** Other names and brands may be claimed as the property of others.*

Comment: Thanks for the response. So all being said I can just go and buy a laptop with HD 4000, buy a 3D monitor (with passive glasses is ok from the link you sent), open up my favorite media player and play a 3D clip and all should work?

Comment: Following link helps out a lot: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/3d/3370919/how-upgrade-your-pc-for-real-3d/